# MySQL bulk update statement in Python

Tags: python, mysql, bulkinsert

I wonder how I can do a bulk update using MySQL and Python. My requirement is like

```
for x in range(0,100):
NNN = some calculation
ABC = some calculation
query = update XXX set value = NNN, name = ABC where id = x
con.execute(query)
```

The problem here is it is executing 100 DB queries and makes the update process slow. Is it possible to have one DB call? I know bulk insert syntax on MySQL but it seems to be non-working with the `update` statement.

Comment: it is some mathematic calculation using python for instance ABC = (200 * 2.5) / 22 and NNN = ABC * 100 / 10 kind of

Comment: They should easily be converted to SQL calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree we can do the calculation on the query. But it is not flexible for change and maintenance. Going for a MYSQL Stored Procedure is a nice option. But I have solved it in python scripts using the following steps. 1. Created a temp table to hold columns A, B and id. Python & MySQL support Bulk insert (see petefreitag.com/item/379.cfm). 2. issue a simple update statement to update the fields using id in where condition. Thats fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL update manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), you can do

```
UPDATE tableX SET NNN = calculation, 
   ABC = (SELECT whatever FROM whatevertable WHERE condition) 
 WHERE x >=0 AND x <=100
```

Comment: The calculation is bit complex that it can't be done in mysql statement itself. also NNN and ABC calculations are interdependent

Comment: You might still be able to squeeze it into a single query in both cases. If you put some more details, we might be able to help. I have done complex interdependent updates on a single query which drastically increases the efficiency of the application.

Comment: I have a query like 'select id, value1, value2 from TABLEA' 
result = cursor.fetchall(): 
for row in results:
X = caculations ( that depends on couple of other select statement and other values)   and Y = X + (again values from other select statements and calculations) 
update TABLEB set A = X, B = Y where id = row['id']

Comment: update TABLEB set A = X, B = Y where id = row['id'] and its inside the for loop.

Comment: These should be easily doable in SQL. For dependent calculations, you might just need to repeat the calculation as the variables are not accessible across the update. So, just repeat the calculation of ABC in NNN. Still this will be faster than the FOR loop in most cases.

Comment: I agree we can do the calculation on the query. But it is not flexible for change and maintenance. Going for a MYSQL Stored Procedure is a nice option. But I have solved it in python scripts using the following steps. 1. Created a temp table to hold columns A, B and id. Python & MySQL support Bulk insert (see http://www.petefreitag.com/item/379.cfm). 2. issue a simple update statement to update the fields using id in where condition. Thats fixed my problem.